# GNC 255 display font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What's the font used on the display of the Garmin GNC 255 ?
[image: GNC 255 front view]

(image taken from the user manual for the GNC 255)

I tried WhatTheFont already, but none of the fonts it showed really matched.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a "font", meaning "digital typeface". It is a low-resolution square-pixel display with bitmapped symbols built in.

Comment: Yeah, but is there a font that looks similar ? I want to simulate the display in a flight simulator, and would like to avoid having to draw the font myself ! :(

Comment: This is unlikely to be an actual font you can download. Sure, there are fonts that look similar. WhatTheFont shows quite a few.